# Need help connecting a speaker to a video card

Tags: wiring, speakers, video, card

I have this video card which uses a 4-pin JST connector for the speaker:

[image]

PL+ PL- PR- PR+

[image]

I was using this speaker which has a 4-pin JST connector:
[image]

[image]

What I thought is:

1. One red wire is for the left (wire 1.)
2. one red wire is for the right (wire 4.)
3. Two black wires are for GND (wire 2 and 3.)

This is not the case as when I checked this speaker, I found the left side black and red wire are shorted and the right side black and red wire are shorted.

What I need help with is now I have a set of speakers with USB and a jack:
[image]

I can give power to the speaker from the USB port but I'm **not*** sure how to do the wiring for the female jack to the 4-pin JST connector (for video card 2.)

**Edited 1:
After talking to the distributor, they gave me details of whatever they knew.**

Video Card 2 (I want to connect the speakers to Video card 2:

[image]
[image]

1. New Board
   [image]
2. Impedance should be 8 Ohm for connected speakers.

**Edited 2: Need help with Female 3.5 mm jack to 4 Pin JST connector connection**
[image]

Comment: How did you determine the wires are "shorted?" The DC resistance of a speaker coil can easily be lower than a multimeter's continuity threshold. I.e. just because it beeped doesn't mean it's shorted.

Comment: @TypeIA Okay, I didn't know that. If that's the case can I directly split the Speaker Aux to Left & GND and Right & GND?

Comment: Measure ohm instead of doing a "beep test" (depending on how good your multimeter is).

Comment: The image is blurry and you drew on top of the chip markings. Is there a manual for that board? There is a good likelihood that the speakers are driven in a bridged fashio so the black leads are not grounds and they must not be connected together or the chip will fry. The board with spepaker amplifier is meant to drive speakers, if you want a line level audio output, you must take the audio before the speaker amplifier chip. Unless it's integrated and there is no line level audio available.

Comment: ok, wait, you are sure, or NOT sure how to do the wiring?

Comment: @Justme There's no manual for this board, I have asked the distributor and they gave me the picture. I have attached it now. And I asked the distributor, he told me the red ones are positive and the black ones are negative (in Old Speaker). And the speaker impedance should be 8 Ohm.

Comment: @Roland My bad, I'm NOT* sure.

Comment: what have you tried out yourself? Are you afraid of trying something? Afraid you will ruin the board? Is this expensive? Is this old? Is it worth it to do all this trouble?

Comment: @Roland Yeah, the Video Card 2 board cost $400 not only that it will take a month to get a new one if this got damaged.